# How can I get an output of a compound interest for every year of the time the amount is invested, using a function and a loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, logic, formula

this is the code I have written, I couldn't get the expected result.
I always get one amount that repeats 8 times.

```py
amount = float(input('the principal amount: '))
rate = float(input('annual rate of return: '))
time = int(input('how many years it will take: '))

def invest(amount, rate, time):
    total = amount * (1+rate)**time
    print(total)

for t in range(time):
    total_new = amount * (1+rate)**time
    print(total_new)

invest(amount, rate, time)

expected outpout for invest(100, 0.05, 8):

year1: $105
year2: $110.25
year3: $115.7625
.
.
.
.
.
year8: $147.745544379
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your variable in the loop, put `t` instead of `time`:

```py
        for t in range(1,time):
          total_new = amount * (1+rate)**t
          print(total_new)
```

Comment: It was hard dealing with this code for me since I am learning recently, but your comment helped me a lot to undertand the logic of this code as well as the anser of  Gderu. Thank you LiavC and Commander Tvis.!

Answer (score 1):

Your function is correct, the problem is only in your for loop.
It should be like this:

```
for t in range(time):
    total_new = amount * (1 + rate) ** t
    print(total_new)
```

Your mistake was setting everything to the power of time, instead of to the power of t. The variable t was changing, while time stayed the same, so you got the same result 8 times.

Besides that, I would also suggest using parenthesis around (1 + rate) ** t just to make it clear that it is happening before the multiplication by amount.

Comment: NOw I got it , as you said the power of "time" was kind of fixed while "t" was changing. Therefore It was nesesary to chage "time" by "t" so that the new amount would get different values based on "t" which was set to 8 time. Thank you Gderu!